# Why in C# with reflection we can set the value of property with private set, but can not invoke the private method

Tags: c#, reflection

GetMethod only searches the public method, but with GetProperty, we get the public auto property with a private set, and we can set the value to this property. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: By default reflection always searches only public things (you can also include privates with a parameter). Since the property is public, it finds it, even though the setter (or even the getter for the matter) happens to be private.

Comment: You can definitely invoke private methods using reflection. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/135482

Comment: Restrictions imposed by the C# language ≠ restrictions imposed by the CLR, IL or Reflection. C# is often more restrictive (and safer).

Comment: Technically speaking, the property itself has an accessibility, apart from the `get` and `set`, just that C# always enforces the wider of the two. So `GetProperty` searches that accessibility

Answer (score 1):

A method has only the one accessibility level, whatever you've defined for that method. The `GetMethod` overloads that don't take a binding flags search only the public methods. It's simply how `GetMethod` was implemented.

Properties have an accessibility level for each of the `get` and the `set`. `GetProperty` overloads that don't take binding flags also search only the public properties; if either `get` or `set` are public, you'll get the property you're searching for (if it exists of course).

The private setter of the property allows access to set the property through reflection as long as the calling code [has permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection#accessing-members-that-are-normally-inaccessible) to get to the private property's set method (see [Security Considerations for Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection)). Remember, an auto property is backed by a private field and has two methods (internally generated getter and setter).

Comment: OP did say "property with private set", but to help with completeness for future readers: some read-only property implementations use [expression-bodied members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764532/3791245). Per the end of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706485/3791245), such implementations can't be set via the usual reflection methods (e.g. `PropertyInfo.SetValue`).